# Get weekly changes (progress)

Tags: mongodb

I have the following objects in the `Games` collection:

```
{
    _id      : 1,
    UserID   : 420,
    MaxValue : 235.23,
    Date     : ISODate("2017-08-02T00:23:44.553Z")
},
{
    _id      : 2,
    UserID   : 420,
    MaxValue : 452.23,
    Date     : ISODate("2017-08-06T00:23:44.553Z")
},
{
    _id      : 3,
    UserID   : 420,
    MaxValue : 281.02,
    Date     : ISODate("2017-08-15T00:23:44.553Z")
}
```

The question is: **how can I get the percentage of MaxValue progress over the week (== weekly progress)?** For example, if we take `_id: 3` object's `Date` field and compute `420`'s user progress, it will look like

> Progress over the last week in percentage (**current date: Aug 6, 2017**) = (452.23 - 235.23) / 235.23 = **~92%**
>
> Average progress over the last week (**current date: Aug 6, 2017**) = (452.23 + 235.23) / 2 = **343.73**

Then, for the next week, we take the computed average of the previous week. It will look like:

> Progress over the last week (**current date: Aug 15, 2017**) = (281.02 - 452.23 ) / 343.73 = **- 49%**
>
> Average progress over the last week (**current date: Aug 15, 2017**) = ( 281.02 +  343.73 ) / 2 = **321.375**

Hence, this is how it looks like if we compute progress manually (by hand).

Therefore, the question is the same, but how to do that using MongoDB *aggregation / mapReduce*? And, for this specific measurement (progress), should I create a separate table for this measurement (weekly progress), or rather, store them in *Games* collection?

Comment: It really depends on how you define the "progress". If this simply is "consistently" the difference between "minimum" and "maximum" values from a given range, then there are indeed functions for that. If you are actually asking to track the changes "between each interval", then that becomes a matter of "storing globals" as you iterate between each sequence, then this becomes more cumbersome. For instance in the from Aug 15 example, how would you get the 235.23 number? Because that actually is not present in the "last week" and is therefore a "progress" indicator carried from the last result.

Comment: By progress, I mean the difference between current week and latest week (when the user played a game for the first time and his or her first object was inserted into the Games collection). So, I do not compare weeks like `progress_for_week_5 = week_5.MaxValue - week_4.MaxValue`, rather, I compare *overall* progress (from the first game ever played). This is why I am resorting to the *average* (which I compute above) to get the overall progress percentage. And, as of Aug 15, I was mistaken: must be `281.02` instead of `235.23`. Hence, I want to track changes *"between each interval"*.

Comment: Exactly. So what you basically need is "calculation between each record", and unless you actually need to "summarise" a number of documents for each interval then it's not actually an "aggregation" per se. You are talking about the differences between the "last seen" and the "current", and then keeping a "global" from the calculated differences. This is not actually something that either `aggregate()` nor `mapReduce()` actually does, and it's really just "cursor iteration" and code. You can "force" mapReduce to store "globals", but like I said, you don't appear to be "aggregating" here.

Comment: So, what would you suggest in this case? Store `GlobalProgress` field (for example) in a separate collection? or, rather, just add another field in the same collection?

Comment: Actually what I'm telling you is that where the above is actually the accurate representation of the data and you do not need to "aggregate" a number of results in order to represent each of the three items, then in fact all you do here is "iterate the cursor". There is no process that does this. It's simple cursor iteration, doing the calculations in between them. I could give you a silly map reduce example that does not actually "reduce", but it's kind of pointless given the results are squashed into a single BSON document, when you can simply iterate a cursor.

Comment: @NeilLunn what if I need to return **top 5 users with highest progress**? I do not think iterating the cursor will be optimal solution here, unless it is the only one. This is why I mentioned MapReduce / aggregation

Comment: Make your example in your question something that actually represents your **real use case**. At risk of sounding like a broken record ( for those who remember what that is ) the aggregation framework nor mapreduce offer "comparison between results", be that plain documents or aggregated sets. This is basically what I keep telling you. You instead "iterate to compare". Whether the "document" to compare is "pre-aggregated" or "aggregated from process" is of little consequence. Aside from "shoehorning into an array" there simply is no way to compare one against the other. Iterate instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151058/discussion-between-alwaysone-and-neil-lunn).